# difference between object and function in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the exact difference between object and function in javascript when both are instanceof Object?

```
var obj = {};
function t(){}

console.log(obj instanceof Object); //true
console.log(t instanceof Object);   //true

console.log(typeof obj); //object
console.log(typeof t);   //function
```

Comment: A function is an object. All objects are instances of Object, ie. arrays, regex, ...

Comment: the function could return a result.

Comment: @leguano and object can't? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function is an object, which *also* has the ability to be *called*.

```
var obj = {};
function t(){}

console.log(obj instanceof Function); // false
console.log(t instanceof Function);   // true

t();   // Works
obj(); // Fails because you can't call non-functions (specifically,
       // the error is `TypeError: obj is not a function`
```

In JavaScript, all functions are objects (just like all `Date` objects are objects), and all objects are `instanceof Object` unless they're created with a `null` prototype:

```
function t(){}
var d = new Date();
console.log(t instanceof Object);                    // true
console.log(d instanceof Object);                    // true
var objWithNullPrototype = Object.create(null);
console.log(typeof objWithNullPrototype);            // "object"
console.log(objWithNullPrototype instanceof Object); // false
```

`typeof` is a very primitive operator, I'm afraid. It'll give you just "object" for most kinds of objects (`Date`, `RegExp`, `Math`), but for functions it goes that little bit further and tells you "function". I go into a bit of depth on `typeof` and its relatives in a post on my anemic little blog: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation...

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript we consider function as objects that we call in our program.Objects is not function you assume like this object is parent and every functions are child of object.

```
var speak = function(what){
    console.log(this);

}

speak("woof");

function test(){
    var a=1;
}
```